# The same Google map Wont work in new domain

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The following code works fine in one domain and in another the map wont show.
Why is this happening?

The content of both sites is exactly the same as the client is in the process of migrating for a new address.

In the old domain the map works fine. In the new one an error appears.

HTML

```
<div id="canvas">              
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScrip

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>
    function initialize() {

    //-----------------------------Stiles --------------------------------:

    var styles = [ { "featureType": "landscape.man_made", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "hue": 

    "#66ff00" }, { "saturation": 43 }, { "visibility": "on" }, { "lightness": -46 } ] },{ 

    "featureType": "landscape.natural", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "hue": "#3bff00" }, 

    { "lightness": -53 }, { "saturation": 33 } ] },{ "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain", 

    "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "water", "stylers": [ { "lightness": 

    -61 }, { "saturation": -60 }, { "hue": "#1aff00" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.highway", 

    "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "hue": "#4cff00" }, { 

    "lightness": -69 } ] },{ "featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", 

    "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": 

    "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "saturation": 57 }, { "hue": "#22ff00" 

    }, { "lightness": -68 } ] },{ "featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", 

    "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "road.local", "elementType": 

    "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "hue": "#55ff00" }, { "lightness": -64 }, { "saturation": 58 } 

    ] },{ "featureType": "road.local", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [ { 

    "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", 

    "stylers": [ { "color": "#ffffff" }, { "visibility": "on" } ] },{ "featureType": "road", 

    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },{ "featureType": 

    "road", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "hue": "#6eff00" 

    }, { "lightness": -2 }, { "saturation": -42 } ] },{ "featureType": "poi", "elementType": 

    "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "color": "#8080ff" }, { "hue": 

    "#66ff00" }, { "saturation": -30 }, { "lightness": -45 } ] },{ "featureType": "poi", 

    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { "color": "#808080" }, { "visibility": "off" 

    } ] },{ "featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "visibility": 

    "on" }, { "color": "#ffffff" } ] },{ "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": 

    "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": "#ffffff" }, { "visibility": "on" } ] },{ 

    "featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [ { 

    "visibility": "on" }, { "hue": "#66ff00" }, { "saturation": 31 }, { "lightness": -76 } ] },{ 

    "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text", "stylers": [ { "color": "#ffffff" }, { 

    "visibility": "on" } ] },{ "featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", 

    "stylers": [ { "color": "#2a6028" } ] },{ "featureType": "transit.line", "elementType": 

    "geometry.fill", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "color": "#97f845" } ] },{ 

    "featureType": "transit.station", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [ { "color": 

    "#ffffff" } ] },{ "featureType": "transit.station", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", 

    "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] } ]


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------:

      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        styles: styles,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.115, -8.251),
        scrollwheel: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                    mapOptions);


    //----------------------------- Marker --------------------------------:

      var image = 'images/logo-map-10.png';
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.11218, -8.25144);
      var tipografiaMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
      });
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------:

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    <script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

js:35 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

Since last summer you have to use API key and restrict it for certain domain.